# Recursively Delete Folders matching "*folder1\folder2"

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to delete all .svn folders ONLY if they are in a CVS folder.  The pattern should be something like this "*CVS\.svn".

However, my attempts at writing a batch script at this is not working at the moment. Here is what I have so far although it doesn't work.

```
FOR /D /R %%X IN (*CVS\.svn) DO RD /S /Q "%%X"
```

or

```
FOR /R CVS %%X IN (.svn) DO (RD /S /Q "%%X")
```

Answer (score 2):

This works if you start one level higher than the "CVS" directory (it's a little more complex otherwise):

```
for /f %d in ('dir /a:d /b /s CVS') do (
  if exist "%d\.svn\." rd /s /q "%d\.svn"
)
```

The first line finds all the directories named "CVS" recursively, then the second deletes the sub-directory ".svn" if it exists. If you're running it from a batch/shell script, use `%%d` instead of `%d`.